# Python Function open,write and call with diff parameters

Tags: python

Currently I have this code.

```
class FileOperations:

def open_files(sys):
    sys.DM = open('DM_FILE.txt','a')
    sys.TM = open('TM_FILE.txt','a')
    sys.AP = open('AP_FILE.txt','a')   

def write_header_to_files(auto):
    global x,y,z
    x= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,HOME PHONE..'
    y= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,OFFICE PHONE,..'
    z= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CCELLPHONE,..'
    auto.DM_FILE.write('x')
    auto.TM_FILE.write('y')
    auto.AP_FILE.write('z')
```

I am calling the class in diff script using

```
filehandle = FileOperations()
filehandle.open_files()
filehandle.write_header_to_files()
```

I am unsure how to call individual files to open within if loop and then write it.

After the help this is what I did.

```
class FileOperations:
  def open_files(self):
    self.file= {
        'DM':open('DM_FILE.txt','a'),
        'TM':open('TM_FILE.txt','a'),
        'AM':open('AP_FILE.txt','a'),
        'DM1':open('DM_EMAIL_FILE.txt','a'),
        'TM1':open('TM_EMAIL_FILE.txt','a'),
        'AP1':open('AP_EMAIL_FILE.txt','a')
               }
def write_header_to_files(self):
global x,y,z
x= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,..
y= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,CO_NAME,PREFIX,..
z= 'PRINT_PUB_CODE,PREFIX,FIRST_NAME,
self.write={
        'MD'  : DM_FILE.write(x),
        'MT'  : TM_FILE.write(y),
        'PA'  : AP_FILE.write(z),
        'MD1' : DM_EMAIL_FILE.write(x),
        'MT1' : TM_EMAIL_FILE.write(y),
        'PA1' : AP_EMAIL_FILE.write(z)
               }
```

would really appreciate if someone can say is this code correct for what I want.Also how can I call this function from another script.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FileOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {
            'DM' : open('DM_FILE.txt','a'),
            'TM' : open('TM_FILE.txt','a'),
            'AP' : open('AP_FILE.txt','a')
        }   

    def write_header_to_file(self, file_id):
        global x
        self.files[file_id].write(x)

filehandle = FileOperations()
filehandle.write_header_to_file('DM')
filehandle.write_header_to_file('TM')
```

Comment: How I am passing diff values?

Comment: The first argument to any function declaration within a class is a reference to the class instance itself (except with certain decorators). You should always name this parameter `self`.

Comment: filehandle.write_header_to_files(self) I got that.but each write are diff so, how I get the self.DM and self.DM.write to call

Comment: I think I understand your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: i am trying to get the output from diff script ..typing filehandle = FileOperations().But my need is to open one file at a time and write one at a time.so suppose if=something ..filehandle.self(stuff,DM) and if something filehandle.write_header_to_file('DM').

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirements. Perhaps you can add some code to your question.

Comment: Just updated the code for what I did.really will appreciate if you check the code.Also the syntax I am trying to pull the function is from filename import FileOperatiom..?